# How to display value on label for circular gauge while using rectangularNeedle

Tags: devextreme

I am trying out DevExtreme circular gauge. I am using rectangularNeedle as a valueIndicator. But, along with that, I want to show the "value" in text format on label. My understanding is, value can be indicated using rectangularNeedle or TextClould  but, not using both at the same time. Please tell me how to achieve both?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [subvalue indicator](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxCircularGauge/Configuration/subvalueIndicator/?version=15_2) with 'TextCloud' type in additional to your main rectangularNeedle.